# The reason of using `std::greater` for creating min heap via `priority_queue`

Tags: c++, c++11, heap, priority-queue, min-heap

I am wondering why for creating a min heap using the `priority_queue`, the `std::greater` should be used?

```
std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T> > min_heap;
```

To me, since the smallest value is always located at the top of the heap, the employed class should be `std::less`

**Update:**
On the other hand, since the default behavior of `priority_queue` (max heap) is to hold the greatest value at the top, it looks to me that the `std::greater` should be used for the max heap creation and not for min heap creation

Comment: Where are you looking? I am reading cppreference.com right now and they specify std::less as the default and say substituting std::greater would cause the smallest element to appear as the 'top' rather than the greatest. Just seems to be a matter of convention, no?

Comment: I think this is an excellent question. I find it odd I found so few people questioning this specific design decision. So far, you were the only one that, like me, seems to find it very counter-intuitive this "reverse" usage of the comparator. I won't question the performance reasons behind the decision, but it does not fell natural to me.

Comment: I just ran into this myself while answering another question and it feels especially unnatural when writing your own comparators.

Comment: It's kinda odd. heapify_down is: if greater, then move it down. and heapify_up: if it's not greater, then move it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The logical argument is as follows

1. `std::priority_queue` is a container adaptor; basic memory considerations make the back the preferred place for modifications (with `pop_back()` and `push_back()`) for sequence containers such as `std::vector`.
2. the `priority_queue` primitives are based on `std::make_heap` (constructor), `std::pop_heap` + `container::pop_back` (`priority_queue::pop`) and on `container::push_back` + `std::push_heap` (`priority_queue::push`)
3. `pop_heap` will take the *front* of the underlying storage, and put it at the *back*, restoring the heap invariant afterwards. The reverse goes for `push_heap`.
4. doing `sort_heap` on a `max_heap` (with the max at the front initially) will [repeatedly pop the front to the back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627/819272) and sort the range according to `less` (which is the default comparison operator)
5. hence, the preferred implementation of a `max_heap` is to have the max element w.r.t. `less` at the front, accessed through `priority_queue::top` (underlying `container::front`).
6. one can still debate whether it is intuitive that `priority_queue` with a `std::less` comparator is representing a `max_heap`. It could have been defined as a `min_heap` by reversing the comparator's arguments (but see the comment by @T.C. that with C++98 binders this is rather verbose) everywhere in the calls to the various heap functions. The one (for me) counter-intuitive result would have been that `top()` would then not have given the element with *top* priority

Comment: The `meow_heap` algorithms are definitely in C++98.

Comment: @T.C. you are right, updated, only `is_heap` and `is_heap_until` were added

Comment: Also, you can't negate the comparator; you need a wrapper that swaps the order of arguments. Given how primitive C++ TMP was at the time this was originally designed (think all the `ptr_fun/bind1st/bind2nd` fun), I'm not really surprised they didn't do it.

Comment: @T.C. yes, easy to forget the pain of the old binders and also having to extract `first_argument_type` and `second_argument_type`

Comment: Can someone explain point 5 again ? From what I understood, popping the element from the max_heap is done from the back. So as less orders the elements in ascending order, getting the top element removes the element from the back ? Have I understood it correctly ?

Comment: @Viraj no, as point 3 indicates (and see [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap)), `pop_heap` will take the front and place it at the back.

Comment: @TemplateRex So how does `less` order it in decreasing order such that the max element is a the top ?

Comment: @Viraj the implementation of `pop_heap` uses something called `sift_down` (and `push_heap` uses `sift_up`). You can go look at the [libc++ implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm) or for a more [didacted explanation here](http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/Jesper/heaplab/heapsurvey_html/node7.html#SECTION00322000000000000000).

Answer (score 8):

The C++ heap functions `make_heap`, `push_heap`, and `pop_heap` operate on a [max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap), meaning the top element is the *maximum* when using the default comparator. So, to create a min-heap, you need to use `greater<T>` instead of `less<T>`.

I suspect that a max heap is used instead of a min heap is that it is easier to implement with the `less` operation. In C++, `less` has the special privilege of being the sort of "default" comparator for all STL algorithms; if you only are going to implement one comparison operation (other than `==`), it should be `<`. This leads to the unfortunate quirk that `priority_queue<T, C<T>, less<T>>` means a max-queue and `priority_queue<T, C<T>, greater<T>>` means a min-queue.

Also, certain algorithms like `nth_element` need a max-heap.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why using `less` induces a max-heap, while `greater` induces a min-heap.

Comment: See my edits, but the TL;DR is max-heaps are used elsewhere in C++ so they are the default.

Comment: So, lemme see if I understood you correctly. You meant since `less` is the default comparator and since `max_heap` is more useful, we ended up having a `max_heap` that implemented via `less` instead of `greater`?

Comment: I don't think a max-heap is any easier to implement than a min-heap using less. However, it is certainly easier (and more efficient) to implement `std::sort_heap` from a max-heap, assuming you want the same ordering you would get from `std::sort`, using the same comparison operator. That fact may have contributed to the reasoning.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Because when you pop an element off the heap, you are left with a space at the end, where you can place the element you just popped off (which is the greatest element). In order to get the correct order if you started with a min-heap, you would have to reverse the range when you were done.

Comment: @TemplateRex: It seems to me that implementing `push_heap` and `pop_heap` would be very inefficient with that configuration, unless you used `push/pop_front` instead of `push/pop_back`. But then you couldn't use a `vector` as the underlying container.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley summarized this comment conversation into a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a process that transforms a priority queue into a sorted sequence.

How can we achieve this?

Suppose we have a max heap now, we take the following procedure.

```
HEAP-SORT(A)
    for i = A.heap_size downto 2
        exchange A[1] with A[A.heap_size]
        A.heapsize -= 1
        max_heapify(A)
```

When we finish this procedure, we get an increasing order sequence.

We notice every time when we compare two elements, we always put the larger one to the array back, which implies the smaller one is on the left of the bigger one.

And this matches the idea when we pass a less operator to the std::sort algorithm to get an increasing order sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A `priority_queue` is a data structure that stores elements in a way that the element with the highest priority is always at the top of the queue. By default, the priority of an element is determined by its value. However, you can use a functor to change the way that the priority of an element is determined.

A functor is a small function object that can be used to perform a specific task. In this case, the `greater<int>` functor is used to compare two integers and return true if the first integer is greater than the second integer.

When you use the `greater<int>` functor with a `priority_queue`, the element with the lowest value will be considered to have the highest priority. This is because the `greater<int>` functor will always return true when comparing the element with the lowest value to any other element.