# std::priority_queue and make_heap API design

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, priority-queue

I was reading the documentation for priority_queue (basically a wrapper over make_heap), and it found out that you can customize it with a compare function.

From the documentation(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> A user-provided Compare can be supplied to change the ordering, e.g.
>   using std::greater would cause the smallest element to appear as
>   the top().

In Wikipedia and other CS texts a heap is defined as such:

> In computer science, a heap is a specialized tree-based data structure
>   that satisfies the heap property: If A is a parent node of B then the
>   key (the value) of node A is ordered with respect to the key of node B
>   with the same ordering applying across the heap. A heap can be
>   classified further as either a "max heap" or a "min heap". **In a max
>   heap, the keys of parent nodes are always greater than or equal to
>   those of the children and the highest key is in the root node.**

But in the std::priority_queue implementation, supplying std::greater would cause a MinHeap to be created (smallest element at the top). I would have expected a max heap since a heap ordering is defined (in all the literature that I've read) if (parent comparator children) is true.

I find this kind of API design confusing.

Was there a reason to define it this way?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748069/the-reason-of-using-stdgreater-for-creating-min-heap-via-priority-queue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it confusing too, but from a somewhat different perspective. Suppose that you want to sort a sequence in ascending order. There are several ways of doing it:

1. Put your data in a `std::vector` or `std::deque` and run `std::sort()` using **`std::less`**.
2. Put your data in a `std::list` and run `std::list::sort()` using **`std::less`**.
3. Insert your data in a `std::set` that is configured with **`std::less`** and in the end it is automatically sorted.
4. Put your data in a `std::vector` or `std::deque` and run `std::make_heap()` followed by `std::pop_heap()`-s using **`std::less`**.
5. Push your data through a `std::priority_queue` using **`std::greater` (!!!)**.

As we can see, `std::priority_queue` is a definite outlier from such a point of view.

Actually, the reason behind the confusing behavior of `std::priority_queue` in this regard is hidden in item (4) since that is what a `std::priority_queue` does underneath. (4) is also against my intuition (though to a lesser extent), since in the intermediate state (while not all `std::pop_heap` have been performed) the sorted part of the sequence is in its upper range, rather than the lower range.

But it also explains why a max heap was selected for the standard library - `std::pop_heap` puts the popped element in the location, from where it can be removed in constant time, regardless of the container type used.

Answer (score 3):

This is something to get your head around - supplying `std::greater` will actually produce min heap.

The reason for this is following: from the heap perspective, comparator defines *lesser than* relation on the heap, even if it is actualy doing something else. When `std::priority_queue` needs to insert elements, it calls the comparator and gives it two elements. If comparator returns `true`, it considers the first element to be smaller than the second, and put's the second element first (since `std::priority_queue` is a *max heap* implementation). As a result, you end up with min heap.

Comment: I understand how it's implemented, but why was it defined this way? 

Why doesn't it just use the comparator to verify the parent/children relationship like it is defined almost everywhere?

Comment: Why does a max_heap need std::less<> instead of  std::greater<>? 
It just needed to switch the order of the 2 elements in the if, and all would work - generate a maxHeap with std::greater.

My first guess was that it's some kind of an optimization, but I'm not sure that is the actual reasoning behind it.

For example the std::sort APIs work the other (intuitive) way around, if the comparator is true, things remain in place...

Comment: @AlexandruEne std::greater is the reverse-order less. I assume that C++ implemented a max-heap by default because it makes heap-sort slightly easier (move the greatest element to the end of the array, which is the newly opened slot).

Comment: @AlexandruEne: "*I understand how it's implemented*" And yet, your description of the behavior was wrong, as Sergey pointed out.

Comment: In the question I described my expectations based on literature, not the implementation, and I was trying to understand "why this implementation was chosen" since it leads in my opinion to a confusing interface. What was the reason behind it? Why doesn't the comparator method define the parent-children relationship? I can see what the code is doing, but I didn't understand why this route and design was chosen.

Comment: @AlexandruEne, comparator is to return true when first element is less than another because this is how every other comparator works in the library. Why `priority_queue` is a max-heap implementation is a different question, and there is a guess about the reasoning in another answer.