# Why does priority_queue in STL not follow strict weak ordering?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, strict-weak-ordering

i Have been playing around with STL containers and the compare function/functors they supports, however i found priority_queue doesn't follow the usual strict weak ordering , i am trying to understand what might be the reason but not able to figure it out, any pointers would be helpful.

It also mentioned in this blog that priority_queue doesnt follow strict weak ordering. [enter link description here](http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/)

```
#include "STL.h"
#include "queue"
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"
#include "functional"
using namespace std;

typedef bool(*func)(const int& val1 , const int& val2);

bool strict_weak_order_function(const int& val1 , const int& val2){
    return val1 > val2;
}

bool comparer_function(const int& val1 , const int& val2){
    return !strict_weak_order_function(val1 , val2);
}

struct Compaper_functor{
    bool operator()(const int& val1 , const int& val2){
        return !strict_weak_order_function(val1 , val2);
    }
};


void runPriorityQueue(void){
    //priority_queue<int , vector<int> , func > pq(comparer_function);
    priority_queue<int , vector<int> , Compaper_functor > pq;
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    while(size--){
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        pq.push(val);
    }
    while(!pq.empty()){
        cout <<'\n'<< pq.top() << '\n';
        pq.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: " i found priority_queue doesn't follow the usual strict weak ordering" Citation needed.

Comment: do you mean that the ordering is reversed? i.e. a predicate of less<> inserts lower items at the back of the priority_queue?

Comment: @arup `priority_queue` does require a strict weak ordering. You need to re-evaluate your assumptions!

Comment: https://ideone.com/8kR9qQ  , according the the functor is 5 < 4 , 5 should be placed ahead of 4, so even though the functor returns false 5 is still placed ahead of 4. This should not be happening with strict weak ordering right?

Comment: @arup That is because your functor doesn't implement SWO.

Comment: @juanchopanza can you please explain briefly.

Comment: @arup Read the answer below.

Comment: @juanchopanza i am refering to this code for you: ideone.com/8kR9qQ

Comment: Maybe [RTFM](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the negation of your `strict_weak_order` (that uses `>`) is `<=` and that is not a strict weak order. A strict weak order `R` has to satisfy `x R x == false` for all `x`. However, `R` equal to `<=` yields `(x <= x) == true`.

You need to reverse the order of arguments (which corresponds to `<`) instead.

```
bool comparer_function(const int& val1 , const int& val2){
    return strict_weak_order_function(val2 , val1);
}

struct Compaper_functor{
    bool operator()(const int& val1 , const int& val2){
        return strict_weak_order_function(val2 , val1);
    }
};
```

Note however that a `std::priority_queue` has a `std::less` as default comparator, but [**that gives a max-heap**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32748069/819272) (i.e. `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` output from the same input), so to get a min-heap (i.e. with output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` from input `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`) you need to pass `std::greater`, see e.g. this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto const v  = std::vector<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    // prints 5 through 1
    for (auto p = std::priority_queue<int> { v.begin(), v.end()  }; !p.empty(); p.pop())
        std::cout << p.top() << ',';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // prints 1 through 5
    for (auto p = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> { v.begin(), v.end()  }; !p.empty(); p.pop())
        std::cout << p.top() << ',';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e22680859464f81c)

Comment: https://ideone.com/8kR9qQ  , according the the functor is 5 < 4 , 5 should be placed ahead of 4, so even though the functor returns false 5 is still placed ahead of 4. This should not be happening with strict weak ordering right?

Comment: @Arup see my expanded answer, and the link to [**the other Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748069/the-reason-of-using-stdgreater-for-creating-min-heap-via-priority-queue) about why priority queue behaves slightly counter-intuitively.

Comment: much appriciated.