# Use of std::greater

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am curious about the use of [std::greater](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/). 
When used with `sort`, it outputs the numbers in descending order. But when used with `priority_queue`, numbers are output in ascending order. Why so?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::greater
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <queue>        // std::priority_queue

int main () {
  int numbers[]={20,40,50,10,30};
  std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> pq (numbers, numbers+5);
  std::sort(numbers, numbers + 5, std::greater<int>());
  while(!pq.empty()){
      std:: cout << pq.top() << ' ';
      pq.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';  
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    std::cout << numbers[i] << ' ';
  return 0;
}
```

The output of above code is:

`10 20 30 40 50 
 50 40 30 20 10`

Or similar lines,

`std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> >` creates a min heap whereas `std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<int> >` creates a max heap. Could have been the other way round. Why is it so?

Comment: Please explain the downvote. Understanding the behavior of constructs used in STL makes a valid question.

Comment: It seems to me like the question you are actually asking is why `std::sort` sorts in the opposite order of `std::priority_queue` and has nothing to do with `std::greater`. Edit : This is not an explanation for the downvote, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Still a fairly good question : mcve + clear + specific + well formatted.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The title gives the clarity of my question. Plus clean code example is provided so as to leave no scope for ambiguity. All we need is just some patience to read the whole question.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I think the down-voter is long gone, FrançoisAndrieux simply addressed your question (and not your downvote).

Comment: @dfri: I do agree. Hence I did not talk anything about downvote in reply to his comment.

Comment: Greater just says if something is greater than another.  It doesn’t imply any specific behaviors associated with the result.   You could use it to sort in either direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Citing [`std::priority_queue` at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) [emphasis mine]

> A priority queue is a container `adaptor` that provides constant time
>   lookup of the largest (by default) element, at the expense of
>   logarithmic insertion and extraction.
>
> A user-provided `Compare` can be supplied to change the ordering, **e.g.
>   using `std::greater<T>` would cause the smallest element to appear as
>   the `top()`**.

So this order is expected, and does not really relate to how [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) sorts element based on a supplied binary comparison function.

> Sorts the elements in the range `[first, last)` **in ascending
>   order**.
>
> ...
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `first`, `last` - the range of elements to sort
> - `policy` - the execution policy to use. See execution policy for details.
> - `comp` - comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the
>     requirements of Compare) **which returns `true` if the `first` argument
>     is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the `second`**.

As `std::greater` will return `true` if its first argument is *greater than* its second one, we expect the elements to be sorted in descending order when using `std::sort` with `std::greater` as function object for performing comparisons.

---

I.e., [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) just happens to be the function object used for performing comparisons in these two different contexts of your example.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference in behavior for `sort` and `priority_queue`. But still the part of question after "Or similar lines, " remains unanswered. I meant to ask why is it not "A user-provided Compare can be supplied to change the ordering, e.g. using std::**less**<T> would cause the **smallest** element to appear as the top()."? `<functional>` `less` for min heap makes more sense than `greater`. Right?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni that is indeed a different (second), question, and the rationale for that choice (from the C++ standard) already has [an excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749094). I see no reason duplicating that content in my answer here, but I can add the link to it tomorrow when I’m not just accessing SO from my phone.